# Create new worksheet if does not exist, rename based on cell value, then reference that worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 workbooks one has the vba (MainWb), the other is just a template (TempWb) that the code paste values and formulas from the mainworkbook. The TempWb only has one blank sheet named graphs. The code needs to open the xltx file (TempWb), add a sheet and rename based on value in a certain cell on the MainWb (if it does not already exist) and then to reference that new sheet in the copy values process from the MainWb. I tried recording a macro but it didn't really help. I have researched and put some stuff together but not sure if it fits and works. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

This is what I have so far.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ExportSave()

    Dim Alpha           As Workbook 'Template
    Dim Omega           As Worksheet 'Template
    Dim wbMain          As Workbook 'Main Export file
    Dim FileTL          As String   'Test location
    Dim FilePath        As String   'File save path
    Dim FileProject     As String   'Project information
    Dim FileTimeDate    As String   'Export Date and Time
    Dim FileD           As String   'Drawing Number
    Dim FileCopyPath    As String   'FileCopy save path
    Dim FPATH           As String   'File Search Path
    Dim Extract         As Workbook 'File Extract Data
    Dim locs, loc                   'Location Search
    Dim intLast         As Long     'EmptyCell Search
    Dim intNext         As Long     'EmptyCell Seach
    Dim rngDest         As Range    'Paste Value Range
    Dim Shtname1        As String   'Part Platform
    Dim Shtname2        As String   'Part Drawing Number
    Dim Shtname3        As String   'Part Info
    Dim rep             As Long

    With Range("H30000")
        .Value = Format(Now, "mmm-dd-yy   hh-mm-ss AM/PM")
    End With

    FilePath = "C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\FRF_Data_Macro_Insert_Test"
    FileCopyPath = "C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\Backup"
    FileTL = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Text
    FileProject = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2").Text
    FileTimeDate = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H30000").Text
    FileD = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E3").Text
    FPATH = "C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\FRF_Data_Macro_Insert_Test\"
    Shtname1 = wbMain.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2")
    Shtname2 = wbMain.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E3")
    Shtname3 = wbMain.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E4")

    Select Case Range("A1").Value

        Case "Single Test Location"

        Case "Location 1"
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Set wbMain = Workbooks("FRF Data Export Graphs.xlsm")
            wbMain.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FileCopyPath & "\" & FileProject & Space(1) & FileD & Space(1) & FileTL & Space(1) & FileTimeDate & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
            ActiveWorkbook.Close False

            Set Alpha = Workbooks.Open("\\plymshare01\Public\Holiday\FRF Projects\Templates\FRF Data Graphs.xltx")

            For rep = 1 To (Worksheets.Count)
                If LCase(Sheets(rep)).Name = LCase(Shtname1 & Space(1) & Shtname2 & Space(1) & Shtname3) Then
                    MsgBox "This Sheet already exists"
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Next

            Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Name = Shtname1 & Space(1) & Shtname2 & Space(1) & Shtname3
            Set Omega = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name).Sheets("ActiveWorksheet.Name")

            locs = Array("FRF Data Export Graphs.xlsm")

            'set the first data block destination
                Set rngDest = Omega.Cells(3, 1).Resize(30000, 3)

            For Each loc In locs
                Set Extract = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FPATH & loc, ReadOnly:=True)
                rngDest.Value = Extract.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4:D25602").Value
                Extract.Close False
                Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(0, 4) 'move over to the right 4 cols
            Next loc

            With ActiveWorksheet.Range("D3:D25603").Formula = "=SQRT((B3)^2+(C3)^2)"

            ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add
            ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
            ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Graphs").Range("A3:D7"), PlotBy:=xlRows
            ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:=Shtname2

            With ActiveChart
                .HasTitle = True
                .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = Shtname2
                .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
                .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Hz"
                .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
                .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Blank"
            End With

            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Case "Location 2"
        Case "Location 3"
        Case "Location 4"
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Export Failed!"

    End Select
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

 End Sub
```

Run-time error '91'
Object variable or With block not set
code lines

```
Shtname1 = wbMain.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2")
Shtname2 = wbMain.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E3")
Shtname3 = wbMain.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E4")
```

This is supposed to tell the code what to name the new created sheet

**Fixed: Moved under**

```
Set = wbMain = Workbooks("FRF Data Export Graphs.xlsm")
```

**New Error:**
Object doesnt support this property or method
code

```
   If LCase(Sheets(rep)).Name = LCase(Shtname1 & Space(1) & Shtname2 & Space(1) & Shtname3) Then
```

Comment: Then I would define the Variable "rep" as Integer (;

Comment: I would make sure to add `Dim rep as Long` (or `Integer`).  Also, adding `Option Explicit` to the top of your worksheet/workbook module will force you to declare all the integers used, so it'll let you know when you haven't. (I like this because it forces me to declare everything, so nothing is left "to guess" for VB).

Comment: Are you using `Option Explicit`? If so, you'll need to declare all variables. Try declaring `Dim rep as Double`, or whatever number variable you prefer, up top and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I am using `Option Explicit` in the actual project, forgot to put on here. I get a new Error now, I am just going to post my actual project.

Comment: Where is `wbMain` set? I expect that is `nothing` still.

Comment: `Set wbMain = Workbooks("FRF Data Export Graphs.xlsm")` It is the file that is open with this VBA in it. The data transfer part worked, I then tried to add this new code that is supposed to create a new sheet with in the template workbook and paste the values to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things could be happening here

```
Shtname1 = wbMain.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2")
```

You are trying to access three objects and set a third. This means `wbMain` needs to be set and `Sheets("Sheet1")` need to be set and `Range("E2")` needs to exist.

You also, because you are setting `Shtname1` as a string I'd be explicit about what value you want to go in there.

```
Shtname1 = wbMain.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2").Value
```

So with the breakpoint on that line and the locals window open (View > Locals Window) make sure everything is set. If it's not it needs to be. One of those values is not set.

If you do infact `Set wbMain = Workbooks("FRF Data Export Graphs.xlsm")` but it is in a different module or a different sub and `wbMain` is redeclared at the top of this sub these statements are in totally different contexts. The first `wbMain` is a different variable basically.

Comment: I set it but i guess its under the `Shtname1` code. So i moved Shtnames under the set = wbMain.

Comment: New error Object doesnt support this property or method. For `If LCase(Sheets(rep)).Name = LCase(Shtname1 & Space(1) & Shtname2 & Space(1) & Shtname3) Then`

Comment: @Duraholiday There is no `Name` property on the `LCase` function. Watch your parentheses.

Comment: I don't get what you mean, I found this somewhere on here and the person said it worked for him. I am new to this stuff, please explain.

Comment: @Duraholiday `Lcase()` is a function which takes  string and converts all the characters to lowercase. `Sheets(rep)` is a sheet object. What you did there is pass a sheet object to the `LCase` function (which returns a string) then tried to use the `.Name` property on that string. Strings have no properties. What you very likely wanted to do was pass the name of the sheet to the `LCase` function like this `LCase(Sheets(rep).Name)`. Notice the `.Name` is now a property being accessed on the sheet object.

Comment: Oh ok, I changed that line of code to `If LCase(Sheets(rep).Name = LCase(Shtname1 & Space(1) & Shtname2 & Space(1) & Shtname3)) Then` and it worked. Now I am on the last part, How to reference the new sheet. Currently its the Set Omega right under what we were just on. It errors out i think because the `ActiveWorksheets.Name`. The value transfer worked before i changed that.

Comment: @Duraholiday `Set Omega = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name).Sheets("ActiveWorksheet.Name")` is looking for a worksheet that is literally named "ActiveWorksheet.Name". Probably not the case. also `Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)` is the same as `ActiveWorkbook`. So you probably want `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Omega")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89404/discussion-between-duraholiday-and-brad).